# Oracle auto generated check constraint

Tags: oracle, check-constraints

When I create table with columns not null, Oracle automatically creating check constraints to be not null: like this ( query from user_constraints view)

```
NAME                           TYPE SEARCH_CONDITION
------------------------------ ---- ---------------------------------------
SYS_C0036357                   C    "SUPPLIER_ID" IS NOT NULL
SYS_C0036358                   C    "SUPPLIER_NAME" IS NOT NULL
```

So, is there any way to know that constraint created by Oracle(Auto) or it had been created by user.

thank you.

Answer (score 7):

You can look at the `GENERATED` field in the `user_constraints` table (or `all_constraints`).

```
create table t (a number not null, constraint t_pk primary key(a));
select table_name, constraint_name, generated
 from user_constraints
 where table_name = 'T';
```

Gives:

```
T | CONSTRAINT. | GENERATED
----------------------------
T | SYS_C008425 | GENERATED NAME
T | T_PK        | USER NAME
```

Comment: +1, didn't know the GENERATED column. The fact that the name starts with SYS_C is also a clue.